# Some add-ons don't work after EE1 upgrade

Tags: matrix, playa, structure, ee1, string

I've upgraded a site from EE1 to EE2 and a few of the add-ons don't seem to be working inside the templates.

They are working fine inside the Admin area and all the content is showing up in the entries perfectly. But on the front end I'm getting things like:

> M90o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr

Appear where that add-on is trying to output the content.

I can't figure it out! All the add-ons are up to date and I'm using the updated / correct template code for that plugin.

One in particular is Structure:

```
{exp:structure:nav start_from="/{segment_1}" include_ul="no" current_class="selected"}
```

Outputs:

> M10O93H7PQ09L8X1T49CHY01Z5J4TT91FGFR

What do these long mix of characters & numbers mean?!

Add-ons currently causing this to happen are:

- Matrix
- Playa
- Structure
- CE Image

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had an old EE1 add-on in the template, which made all the others just die and display the string/characters.

Answer (score 0):

This one is caused from a pseudo caching that the ExpressionEngine template parser does.  When it finds the same tag multiple times it will replace it with a string like this. The template parser will often run into an issue when the tag is nested in another tag pair.  This being said, the fix is simple.  All you really need to do is add a random string to tag (the one that's throwing the random string) so the template parser won't see it as a duplicate tag.

So

```
{exp:structure:nav start_from="/{segment_1}" include_ul="no" current_class="selected"}
```

Could be changed to

```
{exp:structure:nav start_from="/{segment_1}" include_ul="no" current_class="selected" work="yes"}
```

and it should do the trick.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :( Just still outputs all the characters/numbers.